# Can't get interpreter's version in cmd

Tags: python, windows

I've installed Python 3.10.2 on Windows 10, x64. It's added to path and I don't have any other version of Python on my computer. But when I'm trying to check python version using `python -v` in `cmd`, it only outputs "Python".

[image: screenshot]

Moreover, such commands as `python setup.py build` won't work.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: Maybe the installation got interrupted I guess.

Comment: try python -V or python --version.

Comment: I've already reinstalled it multiple times, nothing's changed

Comment: Did you reboot ?

Comment: @acomrade Follow these [steps](https://medium.com/co-learning-lounge/how-to-download-install-python-on-windows-2021-44a707994013)

Comment: I did reboot, it didn't help

Comment: @Somethingwhatever, i've already did and nothing seems to work. Can something be wrong with my OS?

Comment: @acomrade I would assume maybe the installation or uninstalling python did not go as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that to use `python setup.py command` you have to write a full path to your python interpreter executable file and then write `setup.py build`.
So the result would look like this:

```
C:\some_directory_with_your_setup_file>C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe setup.py build
```

And then it works just fine.

I also want to point out that this problem can occur if you got your Python interpreter from anywhere but MsStore.

Answer (score 0):

Check python version using:

```
python --version
```

Comment: I get the same result for this one

Comment: @acomrade Reinstall python. Maybe, install python 3.9

Comment: I've installed 3.9.7, it didn't help.

Comment: @acomrade What happens if you run this command "  python -i  "  ?

Comment: it's exactly the same thing

Comment: I will let you know if I figure out this error...

Answer (score 0):

Use capital `-V` option :)
Lowercase `-v` is another option.
That's why there are also long options, like here `--version`

As for your other problem, it really depends on `setup.py`, which we do not know about. This is the python script you want to run, so there are chances the problem is with this script or its context. Check the respective project or install/build FAQ may be.

Comment: it doesn't work for any setup.py, just outputs "Python" (for some reason) and that's all